# how to import an html richly formatted text into a textflow at runtime?

Tags: html, apache-flex, actionscript-3, import, richtext

i am trying this:

open google docs, new document, and type in:
hello **world**

(world bolded)

then download it as html(zipped)

i unzip the html file, and save it to the assets folder in src folder of my Flex app

i have a Spark:TextArea instance and i want to do:

```
var importer:ITextImporter = TextConverter.getImporter(TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
myTextArea.textFlow = importer.importToFlow(htmlSource);
```

where htmlSource should point to the saved html file somehow

how do i do this? i tryed embedding, converting to ByteArrayAsset and to String, but i always get the source of the html file and not it's rendered rich text (ie "hello **world**).

this is what i c at runtime:

Untitled documentol{margin:0;padding:0}p{margin:0}.c0{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold}.c3{line-height:1.15;text-indent:0pt;direction:ltr}.c2{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial}.c1{background-color:#ffffff}
hello world

am i clear?
any help?
thanx

Comment: Question is clear, and tried out the downloaded googleDocs, but from what ive seen flex can only recognise some basic html tags. Used htmlText before on components but it just recognises <b> etc, not an entire Html file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at the [Text Converter Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html#TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT) to see what is supported, and also try using `<s:RichText>` as well as `<s:RichEditableText>`.